# Deploy a "remote" docker based service in dcos-vagrant

Tags: apache-kafka, marathon, dcos

I deployed dcos-vagrant on a physical server with 16GB RAM.

I would like to deploy a Kafka container, but I would like the container to be running on another machine (a CoreOS server)

This way, I am not constrained by the local RAM which is mostly eaten up by the bootstrap.

I did not find information on how to do that, any pointer to the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you might be able to add a new node to the existing cluster, but this isn't something dcos-vagrant supports out of the box.

One limitation I can think of is that dcos-vagrant uses a host-only VirtualBox network. You would have to modify dcos-vagrant to use a different type of network first (like NAT or bridged), set up routing to resolve the VM IPs from the external machine, and verify that ingress works.

There may also be other limitations that I don't know about. Feel free to play around with it and make a PR if you figure it out.